# How to get all Events from calendar List using Client Context?

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-object-model

Using Client context how to get all recursive Events...

```
 ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            clientContext.Credentials = cred;
            var oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Upcoming Events");

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where>" +
                              "<DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\"/>" +
                              "<Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Month /></Value></DateRangesOverlap>" +
                              "</Where></Query></View>";


            ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.Load(collListItem);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: what all have you tried?

Comment: I added my Code please check it..

Comment: query looks correct to me what is the error that you see browser/ developer console?

Comment: There is no Error..It display Event.but I want all recursive Event with all repeating occurrence..

Comment: can you try <Now/> instead of <Month/> and try? (I know you may not want to get all but i have faced same issue and had to go with "Now" and then filtering data)

Comment: yes I have try it... but not worked

Answer (score 3):

I think thats not possible using Client object model using CAML queries. You can try [this](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/how-get-calendar-recurrent-events-by-csom-from-sharepoint-2013/) solution instead and see if it works

```
function GetItemsFromCalendarAsmx () {
wsURL = webUrl + “_vti_bin/Lists.asmx”;
var xmlCall =
“<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=’http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&#8217; xmlns:xsd=’http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&#8217; xmlns:soap=’http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/’&gt; <soap:Body>” +
“<GetListItems xmlns=’http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/’>&#8221; +
“<listName>” + calendarGuid + “</listName>” +
“<query>” +
“<Query>” +
“<Where>” +
“<DateRangesOverlap>” +
“<FieldRef Name=\”EventDate\” />” +
“<FieldRef Name=\”EndDate\” />” +
“<FieldRef Name=\”RecurrenceID\” />” +
“<Value Type=’DateTime’><Year/></Value>” +
“</DateRangesOverlap>” +
“</Where>” +
“</Query>” +
“</query>” +
“<queryOptions>” +
“<QueryOptions>” +
“<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>” +
“</QueryOptions>” +
“</queryOptions>” +
“</GetListItems>” +
“</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>”;
var result = [];
$.ajax({
url: wsURL,
type: “POST”,
dataType: “xml”,
async: false,
data: xmlCall,
complete: function (xData, status) {
Core.LogMessage(“Core.GetItemsFromCalendarAsmx-> url: ” + wsURL + ” status: ” + status);
if (status === “success”) {
var root = $(xData.responseText);
root.find(“listitems”).children().children().each(function () {
$this = $(this);
var ids = $this.attr(“ows_UniqueId”).split(“;”);
var rec = $this.attr(“ows_fRecurrence”);
result.push({
“StartTime”: $this.attr(“ows_EventDate”),
“EndTime”: $this.attr(“ows_EndDate”),
“Title”: $this.attr(“ows_Title”),
“Recurrence”: (rec === “1” ? true : false),
“Description”: Core.HtmlDecode($this.attr(“ows_Description”)),
“Guid”: ids[1],
“Id”: ids[0],
});
});
}
},
contentType: “text/xml; charset=\”utf-8\””
});
return result;
};
```